# PHPPGAdmin on Windows - authenticate users against Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, php, postgresql, apache-2.4

I installed PHP, Apache 2.4, and PostgreSQL 9.4.1 on Windows machine which belongs to Windows domain.

My ***pg_hba.conf***:

```
hostnossl   all  postgres     127.0.0.1/32       md5
hostnossl   all  all          127.0.0.1/32       sspi
hostssl     all  all          127.0.0.1/32       sspi
hostnossl   all  postgres     ::1/128            md5
hostnossl   all  soescript    ::1/128            md5
hostnossl   all  all          ::1/128            sspi
hostssl     all  all          ::1/128            sspi
hostssl     all  postgres     .mydomain.com      md5
hostssl     all  all          .mydomain.com      sspi
```

PostgreSQL server is running under AD account with **ServicePrincipalName** privilege (as described [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Configuring_for_single_sign-on_using_SSPI_on_Windows)). I created user account in PostgreSQL with the same name as my AD account.
As mentioned above I installed PHP and Apache on the same machine. 
I installed PHPPGAdmin - a PHP based web interface to PostgreSQL.

When I connect directly to PostgreSQL using PGAdmin (running under AD
account) everything works as expected - I can login using my domain credentials.

When I connect to PHPPGAdmin interface through web browser I cannot login using my domain credentials.

The errors I get are:

```
LOG: connection received: host=::1 port=50395

LOG: provided user name (<my user name>) and authenticated user name (SYSTEM) do not match 
FATAL: SSPI authentication failed for user "<my user name>" DETAIL: Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 91: "hostssl all all ::1/128 sspi

LOG: connection received: host=::1 port=50396 

LOG: provided user name (<my user name>) and authenticated user name (SYSTEM) do not match 
FATAL: SSPI authentication failed for user "<my user name>" DETAIL: Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 90: "hostnossl all all ::1/128 sspi"
```

Apache is running under Local System account (which make sense if you look at the errors above).

How do I convince it to work ?

Thanks in advance.